# Json Deserialize to a sub class's "new" property

Tags: c#, json.net

I've searched for a solution to my problem for quite a while now and seen some ideas that I thought might work out, but I haven't been able to put it all together. Worth mentioning is that I'm quite new to C#.

I have a library that defines a bunch of model classes that is used to deserialize JSON-data into. One of these models are `Application` that has the property `public List<ApplicationField> Fields { get; set; }`

I've been able to make a sub class of Application that I call `MyApplication`. Since I have `MyApplication` I would also like to have `MyApplicationField` that extends `ApplicationField`

I've tried a few approaches and below is the one that I thought had the best chance of succeeding (Unfortunately it didn't):

```
public class MyApplication : Application
{
    new public List<MyApplicationField> Fields { get; set; }
}
```

The Json is then deserialized by the code:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyApplication>
```

I was hoping that the value of the JSON `Fields` property would be mapped into the Fields property of type `List<MyApplicationField>` that I've defined in my subclass `MyApplication`. However it is deserialized into the base class' `Fields` property (Which is of type `List<ApplicationField>`)

**Note:** I am not able to alter the base classes.

Is it possible to achieve the behavior I'm looking for?

Comment: Your question has some conflicting data. Is `MyApplication.Fields` a `List<MyApplicationField>` or a `MyApplicationField`?

Comment: My Bad, I missed that when i was summarizing the code for the post :) Updated now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me, as the default behavior. Can you provide an [example](http://sscce.org/) demonstrating the issue?

```
void Main()
{
    {
        var jsonData = @"{""Fields"":[{""MyProp"":""my prop value"",""Prop1"":""prop 1 value""}]}";
        var myApp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyApplication>(jsonData);
        Console.WriteLine(myApp.Fields[0].MyProp); // "my prop value"
        Console.WriteLine(((Application)myApp).Fields == null); // "True"
    }
    {
        // just to make sure it's not being clever because "MyProp" is specified
        // we'll try this also, which could be deserialized as an Application
        var jsonData = @"{""Fields"":[{""Prop1"":""prop 1 value""}]}";
        var myApp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyApplication>(jsonData);
        Console.WriteLine(myApp.Fields[0].Prop1); // "prop 1 value"
        Console.WriteLine(((Application)myApp).Fields == null); // "True"
    }
}

public class MyApplication : Application
{
    public new List<MyApplicationField> Fields { get; set; }
}
public class Application
{
    public List<ApplicationField> Fields { get; set; }
}
public class MyApplicationField : ApplicationField
{
    public string MyProp { get; set; }
}
public class ApplicationField
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try out the example you provided, and then try to determine any inconsistency between your example and my code. I'll be back with the result!

Comment: I found out that the source code for the library I'm implementing is available on Github. The Application class can be found here: https://github.com/kasperbumbech/Podio.API-for-.NET/blob/master/Podio.API/Model/Application.cs Apparently the bas class maps the json properties to new names, and I guess that's what causing my problems. I tried to use `[DataMember(Name = "fields", IsRequired = false)]` in my subclass but the syntax was not recognized. I'm not sure which using directive to use either. I tried System.Runtime.Serialization without luck. Any idea?

Comment: Well... I hadn't defined the reference in my project :$. Now it all works. Thank you for helping me out!